# make filename from $_.Basename and a ".jpg" String in Foreach Loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

I'm fairly new to powershell and I have a simple problem. I want to convert all colored tif's in a folder to jpg's and then delete the originating tif. I got so far that I can loop through only the colored tifs but have a simple problem when converting building the destiny's name from the $_.BaseName. My code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\" -Filter *.tif | ForEach-Object { if ((magick identify  -format "%[bit-depth]" $_.FullName) -ne 1) {magick convert $_.FullName $_.BaseName + ".jpg"} }
```

That results in some errors for each of the colored tifs of the following:

convert: unable to open image 'Image_006': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3568.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.

How can I use the basename to give the command the destination filename?

Comment: Use the grouping operator `(...)` to force PowerShell to evaluate the string concatenation before passing the value to `magick`: `magick convert $_.FullName ($_.BaseName + ".jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

From the [`about_Operators` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--):

> ### Grouping operator ( )
>
> As in other languages, `(...)` serves to override operator precedence in expressions. For example: `(1 + 2) / 3`

So the solution is to enclose the string concatenation operation in `(...)`:

```
magick convert $_.FullName ($_.BaseName + ".jpg")
```

... which will then cause PowerShell to evaluate `$_.BaseName + ".jpg"` *before* invoking `magick`